# Why is the "Let's chat" message so awkward?

Tags: feature-request, chat

> let us continue this discussion in chat

That's what you get when you click the "Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" link. No capitalization. No punctuation. Awkward "let us" phrasing. What's up with this message? Can we get a better one? At the very least, it ought to have proper grammar.

Comment: Let us go look at my stamp collection

Comment: Hooray for stamps!

Comment: _let us go then, you and I, when the number of comments gets too high_ I think we might be [on to something](http://www.bartleby.com/198/1.html) but I don't know where that leaves Pekka and his stamps.

Comment: it is weired that someone has deleted my post

Comment: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." Nope. This question has been asked *after* and already has an answer.