# Capitalize and punctuate "let us continue this discussion in chat"

Tags: bug, status-completed, automatic-comments, capitalization

Stack Exchange has a feature to help move extended discussions out of comments and into chat, but when you use it, it automatically writes the following message for you:

> let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Could we get the orthography fixed?  I'd like it to read:

> Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/).

That's a **capital letter** at the beginning and a **period** at the end.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/213671

Comment: All automated comments are sentence fragments, not complete sentences.  Sentence fragments *shouldn't* be capitalized and *shouldn't* have a period at the end.

Comment: This isn't a sentence fragment.  "Let us continue this discussion in chat" is a complete sentence.

Comment: Be nice; I had no idea this was a hot-button issue around here.

Comment: @Joe, me and Servy are coming from different angles. The reason for my link was because pluralization and similar very minor grammar changes are, well, very minor. Yes, the "fix" is short, but you have to go through the whole process of making sure it's good. So if starts confusing users, then we should take the time to fix it. If not, well then just leave it. I downvoted because I disagree with your suggestion, not because your post was _bad_.

Comment: +1, the lack of capitalization of things is so annoying. It looks like a broken window.

Comment: @gunr2171, I agree that it's quite minor, and probably not worth the effort to fix, but I'd expect to simply see an answer to that effect.  Having the first response be a comment that someone will bludgeon me to death feels like overkill.  (Even when it's just someone being silly and dramatic.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Will be fixed in the next build. Keep an eye out for revision 2014.5.16.2253 here on meta and 2014.5.16.1611 elsewhere.

Comment: [This (essentially a duplicate)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218452/259867) can also be marked status-completed now.